# Unordered list not aligned like h1 inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a `h1` and `ul` inside a `div`, the `ul` is floated to the right, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to make `h1` and `ul` vertically aligned the same. Can anyone explain to me why this is, and how it can be fixed?

[image: Example]

[Here is the jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/qnny6ga2/3/)

Comment: linke this https://jsfiddle.net/qnny6ga2/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set both the `h1` and the `ul` to have the same line-height. This would make both be vertically centered.

Checkout [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hhnutkfv/) Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted your answer since it was posted first.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `line-height` or you can add `padding` to the `ul`

**Jsfiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/qnny6ga2/4/